# joining 2 data tables without any keys, but with some logical link

Tags: r, data.table

I have 2 data tables: `items` and `category`

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1L) # for reproducibility
category <- data.table(from = c(0,8,15,25,45.5,90,101), 
                       to = c(5,12,20,39,60,100,99999), 
                       class = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))

items <- data.table(weight = sample(0:999,10000,replace=TRUE))
```

I want for each row in "items" a class label, for example if item one has weight of 7, it would pick up class "B".  the category weights don't necessary span all the weights, there could be gaps so catagory A is 0-5, B is 8-12, C is 15-20 etc

I could do this in data frames with the `%in%`, but the "item" dataset has 10 million+ items and the "category" dataset has over 200 categories), therefore I am trying to do this in data table.

How would I go about this?

Comment: you have a nice working example, but no expected output and only partially fleshed-out logic. please expand.

Answer (score 8):

Using the `non-equi` joins (new feature) from the current development version of data.table, `v1.9.7`,

```
category[, to2 := shift(from, type="lead", fill=to[.N]+1L)]
items[category, result := class, on=.(weight >= from, weight < to2)]
```

That's it. For each `category`, corresponding matching rows in `items` is found based on the condition provided to the `on=` argument. Then those matching rows get the corresponding value of `class`.

See installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Comment: THanks for the solution, very elegant. So in principle it it possible to extend these logic to beyond just the two conditions 'weight >= from, weight < to'

Comment: Thanks! All operators except `!=`, i.e., `==, >=, >, <=, <` are allowed. You can have as many conditions to the `on` argument as you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
items$label=cut(items$weight,breaks = c(-1,category$to),right = T,labels = category$class)
```

Comment: This produces an NA when weight is zero

Comment: hi the catagory weights don't necessary span all the weights, there could be gaps like catagory A is 0-5, B is 8-12, C is 15-20 etc..